# How do I get arrowheads to be orientated correctly?

Tags: javascript, svg, path

I have recently been able to get the main part of my code to work, but now I am working on trying to make it look nice. I need to add arrow heads to the end of the vectors, but I have run into a problem of location and orientation. What I want to do is have the point of the arrowhead be at where my vectors stop. Another problem I have is getting the orientation right because as I use the input box to change the ellipse the vectors are going to change angles. Below is my entire code:

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CS 5890</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        rect {
            fill: #9f009f;
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
        polyline {
            stroke: #00ff00;
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 3;
        }
        line {
            stroke: #00ff00;
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 3;
        }
        path {
            stroke: #0000ff;
            fill: #0000ff;
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
        circle {
            stroke-width: 0;
            fill: #009900;
        }
        text {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
Eccentricity: <input id="eccentricity" onchange="eccentricityChanged()"></input>
<p>Enter a value between 0 and 1 for the Eccentricity</p>

Rotation Rate: <input id="rotationRate" onchange="rotationRateChanged()"></input>
<p>Enter a value to change the Rotational Rate</p>
<br>
<svg width="800" height="800" id="diagram">
</svg>
<g id="diagram-elements">
    <path id =''>
</g>
<script src="Vectors.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
function eccentricityChanged() {
  let svg = document.getElementById("diagram");

  let temp = document.getElementById("mytext");
  if (temp) {
    temp.remove();
  }

  temp = document.getElementById("container");
  if (temp) {
    temp.remove();
  }
  let container = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  container.setAttribute("id", "container");
  svg.appendChild(container);

  let s = 100;
  let omega = 0.5;
  let A = 0.2084558583;
  let B = 0.7915441417;

  let e = document.getElementById("eccentricity").value;
  let formFactor = A * e + B;
  let eccent = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e, 2) / (1 - Math.pow(e, 2)));
  let p =
      (1 + 1 / Math.pow(eccent, 2)) * (1 - (1 / eccent) * Math.atan(eccent)) -
      1 / 3;
  let q =
      (1 / eccent) * (1 + 3 / Math.pow(eccent, 2)) * Math.atan(eccent) -
      3 / Math.pow(eccent, 2);
  let omegaStable = Math.sqrt((15 / 4) * q * (1 - (3 / 5) * formFactor));
  let apperantGravA =
      Math.pow(1 - Math.pow(e, 2), -1 / 6) *
      (1 - (1 + p / q) * Math.pow(omegaStable, 2));
  let apperantGravB =
      Math.pow(1 - Math.pow(e, 2), 1 / 3) *
      (1 + ((2 * p) / q) * Math.pow(omegaStable, 2));
  let a = Math.pow(1 - Math.pow(e, 2), -1 / 6);
  let b = Math.pow(1 - Math.pow(e, 2), 1 / 3);
  let scaleFactor = 150;
  let eqRad = a * scaleFactor;
  let polRad = b * scaleFactor;

  let latitude = [Math.PI/12, 5*Math.PI/18, 5*Math.PI/12];
  let latitudeLength = latitude.length;
  var i;

  for (i of latitude) {
    let rho = (a * Math.cos(i)) / Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(e * Math.sin(i), 2));
    let z =
        -(a * (1 - Math.pow(e, 2)) * Math.sin(i)) /
        Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(e * Math.sin(i), 2));
    let lattGrav =
        (a * apperantGravA * Math.pow(Math.cos(i), 2) +
            b * apperantGravB * Math.pow(Math.sin(i), 2)) /
        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a * Math.cos(i), 2) + Math.pow(b * Math.sin(i), 2));
    let gravRho = -lattGrav * Math.cos(i) - Math.pow(omegaStable, 2) * rho;
    let gravZ = -lattGrav * Math.sin(i);
    let accelCent = Math.pow(omega, 2) * rho;
    calculateValues(rho, z, lattGrav, gravRho, gravZ, accelCent, polRad, s);
  }

  makeEllipse(eqRad, polRad);
}

function makeEllipse(eqRad, polRad) {
  let svg = document.getElementById("diagram");

  let temp = document.getElementById("mydiagram");
  if (temp) {
    temp.remove();
  }

  let ellipse = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  ellipse.setAttribute("d", `M 400 100 a ${polRad},${eqRad} 90 1,0 1,0 z`);
  ellipse.style.fill = "transparent";
  ellipse.style.stroke = "black";
  ellipse.style.strokeWidth = "3px";
  ellipse.setAttribute("id", "mydiagram");
  svg.appendChild(ellipse);
}

function calculateValues(
    rho,
    z,
    lattGrav,
    gravRho,
    gravZ,
    accelCent,
    polRad,
    s
) {
  let rho1 = rho * 150 + 400;
  let z1 = z * 150 + 100 + polRad;

  let rho2 = rho1 + s * gravRho;
  let z2 = z1 - s * gravZ;

  let rho3 = rho2 + s * accelCent;
  console.log(rho1, rho2, rho3, z1, z2);

  gravityVector(rho1, z1, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad);
  accelCentVector(rho1, z1, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad);
  apperantGravVector(rho1, z1, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad);
}
```

Vectors.js

```js
function gravityVector(rho1, z1, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad) {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");

    let marker = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "marker");
    marker.setAttribute("id", "triangle");
    marker.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 10 10");
    marker.setAttribute("refX", "0");
    marker.setAttribute("refY", "5");
    marker.setAttribute("markerUnits", "strokeWidth");
    marker.setAttribute("markerWidth", "10");
    marker.setAttribute("markerHeight", "8");
    marker.setAttribute("orient", "auto");

   let path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
   path.setAttribute("d", `M ${rho2} ${z2} l 5 0 l -5 10 l -5 -10 z`);
   path.style.stroke = "green";
   path.style.strokeWidth = "5px";
   container.appendChild(path);

    let arrow = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    arrow.setAttribute("d", `M ${rho1},${z1} L ${rho2} ${z2}`);
    arrow.setAttribute("id", "gravPath");
    arrow.style.stroke = "maroon";
    arrow.style.strokeWidth = "2px";
    container.appendChild(arrow);
    arrow.setAttributeNS("marker-end", "triangle", "void");
}

function accelCentVector(rho, z, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad) {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");

    let marker = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "marker");
    marker.setAttribute("id", "triangle");
    marker.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 10 10");
    marker.setAttribute("refX", "0");
    marker.setAttribute("refY", "5");
    marker.setAttribute("markerUnits", "strokeWidth");
    marker.setAttribute("markerWidth", "10");
    marker.setAttribute("markerHeight", "8");
    marker.setAttribute("orient", "auto");

    let path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    path.setAttribute("d", `M ${rho3} ${z2} l 5 0 l -5 10 l -5 -10 z`);
    path.style.stroke = "black";
    path.style.strokeWidth = "5px";
    container.appendChild(path);

    let arrow = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    arrow.setAttribute("d", `M ${rho2},${z2} L ${rho3} ${z2}`);
    arrow.setAttribute("id", "accelCentPath");
    arrow.style.stroke = "darkorange";
    arrow.style.strokeWidth = "2px";
    container.appendChild(arrow);
    arrow.setAttributeNS("marker-end", "triangle", "void");
}

function apperantGravVector(rho, z, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad) {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");

    let marker = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "marker");
    marker.setAttribute("id", "triangle");
    marker.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 10 10");
    marker.setAttribute("refX", "0");
    marker.setAttribute("refY", "5");
    marker.setAttribute("markerUnits", "strokeWidth");
    marker.setAttribute("markerWidth", "10");
    marker.setAttribute("markerHeight", "8");
    marker.setAttribute("orient", "auto");

    let path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    path.setAttribute("d", `M ${rho3} ${z2} l 5 0 l -5 10 l -5 -10 z`);
    path.style.stroke = "black";
    path.style.strokeWidth = "5px";
    container.appendChild(path);

    let arrow = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    arrow.setAttribute("d", `M ${rho},${z} L ${rho3} ${z2}`);
    arrow.style.stroke = "dodgerblue";
    arrow.style.strokeWidth = "2px";
    container.appendChild(arrow);
    arrow.setAttributeNS("marker-end", "triangle", "void");
}
```

Comment: Hey Paankey56, we cannot run your code snippet directly here because you have 3 separate snippets (not linked). I tried to copy your code into JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/4mauntrj/12/ but there are a lot of errors with your path calculations `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M NaN NaN l 5 0 l …".` so nothing is shown in the SVG. Perhaps you can create a working demo on JSFiddle or similar and share and then I/we can help with the questíon you asked? (Also the formula `rotationRateChanged()` doesn't exist?)

Comment: Hi Alex, so I think i understand what you mean about my path errors, but the program works on the platform I am using, Webstorm. Also when I clicked on your jsfiddle link the program was working so I am confused what you want me to do. Also, I know that the rotationRateChange() doesn't exist, i am still working on that part.